# Remove characters before and after string SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace

I would like to remove all characters before and after a string in the select statement.
In the example below I would like to remove everything before and including `/Supply>` and after and including `>/`
Note the remaining part will be a fixed number of characters.

Any help would be much appreciated

Eg.

```
abs/Supply>hhfhjgglldppprrr>/llllllldsfsjhfhhhfdhudfhfhdhdfhfsd
```

Would become:

```
hhfhjgglldppprrr
```

Comment: Please revise your post.  This is nonsense.

Comment: Post the desired result and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using (SQL Server, MySQL, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PATINDEX()` to identify the position of the patterns you are looking for (`/Supply>` and `>/`) then remove them based on the length of the string:

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(col,LEN(col) - PATINDEX('%/Supply>%',col) -7), PATINDEX('%>/%', RIGHT(col,LEN(col) - PATINDEX('%Supply>%',col) -7))-1)
```

Simply replace `col` in the above with your column name.

**Example below with test string** `abs/Supply>keep>/remove`

First remove everything before and including `/Supply>`:

```
SELECT RIGHT('abs/Supply>keep>/remove',LEN('abs/Supply>keep>/remove') - PATINDEX('%/Supply>%','abs/Supply>keep>/remove') -7)
```

This will give `keep>/remove`

Then remove everything after and including `>/`:

```
SELECT LEFT('keep>/remove',PATINDEX('%>/%','keep>/remove') - 1)
```

This will give `keep`, the part of the string you want.

Here is the combined version, same as above, just includes the test string instead of `col` so you can run it easily:

```
SELECT LEFT(RIGHT('abs/Supply>keep>/remove',LEN('abs/Supply>keep>/remove') - PATINDEX('%/Supply>%','abs/Supply>keep>/remove') -7), PATINDEX('%>/%', RIGHT('abs/Supply>keep>/remove',LEN('abs/Supply>keep>/remove') - PATINDEX('%/Supply>%','abs/Supply>keep>/remove') -7))-1)
```

This will give `keep`.  You can also replace the string above with the one in your question, I just used a different test string because it is shorter and makes the code more readable.

Comment: This works but if the first part of the string is not always 'abs/Supply>' this will no longer work correctly.

Comment: @SeanLange It will always work as long as `/Supply>` is there

Comment: Right. My comment is that if that changes then this will stop working. :)

Comment: @SeanLange That's true - it can be pretty easily adjusted to work with any pattern but I went with the patterns in the question.  The `-7` could be `LEN(pattern) -1` etc.  Side note, I like your answer better if the `>` caveat isn't an issue.  `PARSENAME()` is a cool function to leverage.

Answer (score 0):

If your input always has exactly two instances of ">" you could use PARSENAME.

```
declare @SomeValue varchar(100) = 'abs/Supply>hhfhjgglldppprrr>/llllllldsfsjhfhhhfdhudfhfhdhdfhfsd'

select PARSENAME(replace(@SomeValue, '>', '.'), 2)
```

This will not work correctly if your data also contains any periods (.). We can deal with that if needed with a couple of replace statements. Still very simple and easy to maintain with the same caveat of exactly 2 >.

```
declare @SomeOtherValue varchar(100) = 'abs/Supply>hhfhjgg.lldppprrr>/llllllldsfsjhfhhhfdhudfhfhdhdfhfsd'

select replace(PARSENAME(replace(replace(@SomeOtherValue, '.', '~!@#'), '>', '.'), 2), '~!@#', '.')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    DECLARE @inputStr  VARCHAR(max)= 'abs/Supply>hhfhjgglldppprrr>/llllllldsfsjhfhhhfdhudfhfhdhdfhfsd'
    DECLARE @startString VARCHAR(100)='/Supply>'
    DECLARE @EndString  VARCHAR(100)='>/'
    DECLARE @LenStartString INT = LEN(@startString)
    DECLARe @TempInputString VARCHAR(max)='';

     DECLARE @StartIndex INT
     DECLARE @EndIndex INT

     SELECT @StartIndex = CHARINDEX(@startString,@inputStr)+@LenStartString
     SELECT @TempInputString = STUFF(@inputStr, 1, @StartIndex, '')
     SELECT SUBSTRING(@TempInputString,0,CHARINDEX(@EndString,@TempInputString))
```

In Single Line

```
    DECLARE @inputStr  VARCHAR(max)= 'abs/Supply>hhfhjgglldppprrr>/llllllldsfsjhfhhhfdhudfhfhdhdfhfsd'
    DECLARE @startString VARCHAR(100)='/Supply>'
    DECLARE @EndString  VARCHAR(100)='>/'

    SELECT SUBSTRING(STUFF(@inputStr, 1, CHARINDEX(@startString,@inputStr)+LEN(@startString), ''),0,CHARINDEX(@EndString,STUFF(@inputStr, 1,CHARINDEX(@startString,@inputStr)+LEN(@startString), '')))
```